# Angular in neither browser nor node environment

Tags: node.js, angularjs, apple-tv, service-provider

I'm trying to pull a crazy trick and I am kinda stuck.

What I need to do is to use angular on AppleTV. What's the purpose of using angular on something that doesn't have DOM at all? I'm trying to reuse bunch of angular services, written for another app, so I need to use `serviceProvider` part of angular and its dependency injection mechanism. I probably could use [node-di](https://github.com/vojtajina/node-di) for dependency, probably that still wouldn't solve `serviceProvider` part.

Generally what I need to be able to do is to load angular.js code (maybe via XHR) and eval it.
Currently I wasn't able to do it, angular has tons of dependencies on DOM objects. 
I tried loading angular, using [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), it worked on node, but didn't on AppleTV. Jsdom by itself too coupled with node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to eval it by mocking out all DOM dependencies

```
  Location = ->
  Location.prototype.href = ""
  Location.prototype.pathname = ""

  Window = ->
  Window.prototype.location = new Location()
  Window.prototype.addEventListener =  ->
  window = new (Window)
  global.window = window

  Element = ->
  Element.prototype.setAttribute = ->
  Element.prototype.pathname = ""
  Element.prototype.addEventListener = ->
  Element.prototype.find =-> new Element()

  Document = ->
  Document.prototype.createElement = -> new Element
  Document.prototype.addEventListener = ->
  document = new Document()
  global.document = document

  window.document = document
  Navigator = ->
  navigator = new Navigator()
  global.navigator = navigator
```

Comment: Interesting! were you able to run Angular on Apple TV after doing this?